# Merging 3 dict()'s in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Is there a method of logically merging multiple dictionaries if they have common strings between them? Even if these common strings match between values of one dict() to a key of another?

I see a lot of similar questions on SO but none that seem to address my specific issue of relating multiple keys in "lower level files" to those in higher keys/values(level1dict)

Say we have:

```
level1dict = { '1':[1,3], '2':2 }
level2dict = { '1':4, '3':[5,9], '2':10 }
level3dict = { '1':[6,8,11], '4':12, '2':13, '3':[14,15], '5':16, '9':17, '10':[18,19,20]}
finaldict = level1dict
```

When I say logically I mean, in level1dict 1=1,3 and in level2dict 1=4 and 3=5,9 so overall (so far) 1 = 1,3,4,5,9 (sorting not important)

The result I would like to get to is

```
#.update or .append or .default?
finaldict = {'1':[1,3,4,5,9,6,8,11,12,14,15,16,17] '2':[2,10,18,19,20]}
```

Answered:  Thank you Ashwini Chaudhary and Abhijit for the networkx module.

Comment: Currently I produce lists of the values ( list=dict[keys]) for each key in a dictionary. Then I use a for loop looking at each element of those lists which checks for presence, if not append.... a problem I have ran into (in other methods) is that I can usually get the first element to append but all subsequence elements are lost. The "other methods" include .update, .default .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a problem of connected component subgraphs and can be best determined if you want to use [networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/). Here is a solution to your problem

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> level1dict = { '1':[1,3], '2':2 }
>>> level2dict = { '1':4, '3':[5,9], '2':10 }
>>> level3dict = { '1':[6,8,11], '4':12, '2':13, '3':[14,15], '5':16, '9':17, '10':[18,19,20]}
>>> G=nx.Graph()
>>> for lvl in level:
    for key, value in lvl.items():
        key = int(key)
        try:
            for node in value:
                G.add_edge(key, node)
        except TypeError:
            G.add_edge(key, value)


>>> for sg in nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G):
    print sg.nodes()


[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17]
[2, 10, 13, 18, 19, 20]
>>>
```

Here is how you visualize it

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> nx.draw(G)
>>> plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for an apparently working solution, but that seems like overkill

Comment: @acjohnson55: Its not considering OP failed to realize the problem. What you are trying to solve is a connected component subgraph. Either you adopt an algorithm widely available or use networkx

Comment: In all really this data is clustering of biological samples. So the formation of visual clusters is very appealing to me. Will this method take strings instead of numeric numbers?  e.g. 1 would equal 'DEX19.h_1273' ?

Comment: @jon_sheep: Yes, but you should be consistent with node nomenclature

Comment: @abhijit, alright I will give it a shot. All nodes would be strings in the real data set. I am currently using python 2.7.3  is this networkx module available to me?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: networkx is the panacea for all network/graph problems

Comment: @abhijit, downloaded from http://networkx.lanl.gov/ and used the easy_install method. Module still wont import properly

Comment: @Abhijit This module will surely come in handy for problems that come in programming competitions.

Comment: I just think problem this simple deserves a dirty quick hack, not a full armoured problem specific library.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of notes:

1. It's not convenient that some values are numbers and some are lists. Try converting numbers to 1-item lists first.
2. If the order is not important, you'll be better off using [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)s instead of lists. They have methods for all sorts of "logical" operations.

Then you can do:

```
In [1]: dict1 = {'1': {1, 3}, '2': {2}}

In [2]: dict2 = {'1': {4}, '2': {10}, '3': {5, 9}}

In [3]: dict3 = {'1': {6, 8, 11}, '2': {13}, '4': {12}}

In [4]: {k: set.union(*(d[k] for d in (dict1, dict2, dict3)))
    for k in set.intersection(*(set(d.keys()) for d in (dict1, dict2, dict3)))}
Out[4]: {'1': set([1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 11]), '2': set([2, 10, 13])}
```

Comment: I understand this, but I can't fight what my biological pipeline produces :(  However, I will look into sets

Comment: @jon_shep My suggestion is to do some preliminary conversion first and then apply the straightforward `set` methods.

Comment: I could do this, but my true data set is of 100,000 uniq IDs that over 3 files (hence the three dictionaries) gets narrowed down to only 15 ids in "level1dict".  So I think applying this method would be a pain on my rather large dataset.

Comment: @acjohnson55 It looks a little complex because I stuffed everything in a dict comprehension, but the logic behind it is simple. Maybe the command can be simplified, too, suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @jon_shep It will be beneficial if you need to do something else to the data that also has "set logic".

Comment: There is one downstream step after this one. I would like to take the final merged dict() and loop over every value while looking at another file with that values sequence data.  So.. each ID would then get biological data (500-700 digit string of ATCG's) appended to it as well.   This is a tall order for my first real script.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [106]: level1dict = { '1':[1,3], '2':2 }

In [107]: level2dict = { '1':4, '3':[5,9], '2':10 }
In [108]: level3dict = { '1':[6,8,11], '4':12, '2':13, '3':[14,15], '5':16, '9':17, '10':[18,19,20]}

In [109]: keys=set(level2dict) & set(level1dict) & set(level3dict) #returns ['1','2']
In [110]: dic={}

In [111]: for key in keys:
    dic[key]=[]
    for x in (level1dict,level2dict,level3dict):
        if isinstance(x[key],int):
            dic[key].append(x[key])
        elif isinstance(x[key],list):
            dic[key].extend(x[key])
   .....:             

In [112]: dic
Out[112]: {'1': [1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 11], '2': [2, 10, 13]}

# now iterate over `dic` again to get the values related to the items present
# in the keys `'1'` and `'2'`.

In [122]: for x in dic:
    for y in dic[x]:
        for z in (level1dict,level2dict,level3dict):
            if str(y) in z and str(y) not in dic:
                if isinstance(z[str(y)],(int,str)):
                     dic[x].append(z[str(y)])
                elif isinstance(z[str(y)],list):
                     dic[x].extend(z[str(y)])
   .....:                     

In [123]: dic
Out[123]: 
{'1': [1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 11, 5, 9, 14, 15, 12, 16, 17],
 '2': [2, 10, 13, 18, 19, 20]}
```

Comment: I am curious, when you and the answer above use this syntax:  IN [x]: dict()   ...  OUT[y]:"literal printed dict()"    What is this called / doing?  I would enjoy to read up on this personally.

Comment: This is [IPython](http://ipython.org/)  console, here instead of the traditional `>>>` you'll see `IN[]` and `OUT[]`

Comment: Ahh, alright. I have less than a month of python under my belt. Thank you.